# android: Unchecking Checkbox on the fly (state checked=true)

Tags: android

I've read several topics to this but couldn't find any good solution for my problem.

I've one Checkbox which is standard "checked" with state TRUE. I want know to stop my background music if I'm unchecking it - On the fly with no button. **I know that there is something missing but I cant get it! Thanks for ur help!**

**I'm using this Code which has no errors but it doesn't works correctly.**

```
private CheckBox chkBoxMusic;
private MediaPlayer mp_music;
OnClickListener checkboxListener;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.sound);
    mp_music = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.menusong);


    chkBoxMusic = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxMusic);

    checkboxListener = new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();

               if (!checked) {

                   mp_music.stop();
               }     
            }
    };

   chkBoxMusic.setOnClickListener(checkboxListener);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code as by using [CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) for checkbox:

```
chkBoxMusic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( !isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
             mp_music.stop();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur recent answer! it works, but the problem is my background music. This activity with the checkbox is the settings activity and my music is playing from the menu activity...hm..just thinking, any suggestion again? else thanks for ur help!

Comment: maybe i've to set my background music as a public var? so that all my activities are able using it?

Comment: ok if i'm correct you have two Activity A and Setting Activity you want to stop music from Setting Activity and music is currently playing in Activity A?right

Comment: no. if i uncheck the music in the settings, it should be stopped overall. if its on, it should play overall :-) I think i need a public var for my music? music is playing after app starts

Comment: No, you will need a service which play music for use and start this service from your First Activity . from Setting Activity you will need to Broadcast an intent using Broadcast receiver for sending CheckBox click unlicked event to Service for stopping/starting music

Comment: and second solution is use SharedPreferences  for storing music state means it's playing or not on First Activity and use a Thread to watch changes in SharedPreferences .in Setting Activity store check box click / un clicked  state in SharedPreferences.

Comment: puhh ok. how does this looks like? sry, never had to do with this. At the mom i ve definied :  private mediaplayer mp_music; mp_music = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.menusong); and thats it. so i hear in all activities my music

Comment: i give you both solution which is best for you you can choose it thanks